# Cross Platform Mobile Application SDKs: Write Once Deploy Everywhere

Tags: android, ios, deployment, mobile, air

I am interested to find out if there are any good platforms that are cross platform compatible for business apps.  I know that Adobe AIR for Mobile is good for business apps and can be compiled for both Android and iOS devices(iPhoone/iPad).  Outside of AIR, I don't know of any.  I've looked at Corona, Unity, and Shiva 3d, but these seem to only be oriented towards game development.

My problem using AIR for Mobile is that from the experimental apps I've done in this fashion, the performance of AIR apps on Android and iOS always seem to be sluggish.  Are there other SDKs that support a more responsive "write once deploy everywhere" model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you'll find a great article - http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/

it contain mainly 5 of them -

1) [RhoMobile](http://rhomobile.com/)
2) [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
3) [WidgetPad](http://widgetpad.com/)
4) [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)
5) [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)

if you are looking for great performance then go for Appcelerator. It convert JS code in native app.. so performance is as good as native app.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at MonoTouch and Mono for Android from Xamarin? http://xamarin.com/

They say you can re-use up to 90% of your application logic across iOS and Android phones and tablets, and Windows Phone and then create device-native user experiences / UI with access to all the native platforms API and device sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PhoneGap http://phonegap.com/. However, testing this myself I have also found slugish performance. Having looked around on the web there is a strong battle of native vs the write once run anywhere solutions with the native option seeming faster.

Answer (score 0):

check out [www.madewithmarmalade.com](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com).

Its allows you to write directly down to the bare metal, creating a single native binary that means you don't compromise speed, which I've found the problem with a number of proposed solutions.

There an English outfit, part owned by ARM, so the tech is pretty good.

For $499, you can't go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [AeroGear](http://aerogear.org/) you can try.